# DBT Test execution create an HTML File or GUI Reporter

Tags: dbt, dbtype

Hello everyone I would like to ask for your assistance if there's a way I could create an HTML/GUI Report upon running "dbt test" command. Your response is highly appreciated.

This is the result I got upon running dbt test

[image: Explorer Screenshot]

[image: Terminal Scerenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some 3rd party libraries that will generate reports like the one you're looking for. One you can try is called Elementary Data (https://www.elementary-data.com/). When you run DBT tasks, it creates a schema with all of the stats on model execution timings, test results, etc. It then has a command to generate an HTML page using those results to publish some simple graphs and aggregate test results.